# Чтение данных по байтам

Tags: java

Передаю данные в 16-ричном виде. Вот посылка

> 01 0f 00 19 00 00

И дальше в коде разбираю эти данные. Вот код:

```
ByteBuffer tel=ByteBuffer.wrap(inData);
agg_id   =   tel.getInt(0);
status   =  tel.get(4);
```

Посылка в 10-тичном виде выглядит вот так вот:

> 1 15 0 25 0 0

Все элементы в int типе. Первый со значением 1 храниться в одном байте. Второй в 2 байтах и третий в 4 байтах. Но в результате в agg_id записывается значение -2 милиона примерно. Хотя должна единица которая храниться в первом байте. Почему так происходит? Может я как то не так понимаю.

Comment: 1, 2 и 4 байта это 7 байт. У вас 6. Так и надо?

Comment: Инициализируйте `inData` прямо в коде проблемными значениями, уберите строку со `status` и получится нечто похожее на [МСВП](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @D-side нет. Это ошибка. Но разве она может повлиять на первый байт?

Comment: @defaultlocale тут немного проблематично, так как это не java проект, а работа в tibco. И там просто элемент работающий с java кодом. А данные передаются по tcp.

Comment: @Андрей вынесите код в Java проект и воспроизведите ошибку. Если не воспроизведется, то значит проблема не в приведенном коде, а где-то еще (например в передаче данных). Если воспроизведется, то можно будет задать более точный вопрос.

Comment: @defaultlocale понял вас. Попробую.

Answer (score 1):

Документация к [`ByteBuffer.getInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#getInt(int)) утверждает, что считывается четыре байта, что логично для `int`:

> Reads four bytes at the given index, composing them into a int value according to the current byte order.
>
> Считывает четыре байта по заданному индексу, собирая их в целочисленное значение соответственно текущему порядку байтов.

Попробуйте использовать [`byte get(int index)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#get(int)):

```
agg_id = tel.get(0);
```

Comment: пробовал, так всё нормально. Но как сделать то же самое с getint(0)?

Comment: @Андрей писать и читать `int` как четыре байта, больше никак

Comment: То есть если у меня 2 интовых числа вписаны по порядку и занимают по 2 байта каждое, то getInt соберёт первые 4 байта(в моём случае эти 2 числа) и преобразует их в одно? Я правильно понял?

Comment: @Андрей именно, `getInt` считывает 4 байта в любом случае. Можете полученное значение сами затем делить на байты, но через `get` удобнее.

Comment: Понял вас. Спасибо за объяснение.

Comment: @Андрей Пожалуйста!

Comment: Ещё появился вопрос. Если не сложно. Разбираю я в коде c# число 128, а собирается с помощью getInt -128. В чём дело? В конвертации? Если нужно могу привести код c# в вопрос.

Comment: Или что то нужно поменять в java коде?

Comment: Сложно сказать. Нужно определить точно где возникает проблема: в передаче данных (взаимодействие C# и Java), либо уже при обработке (ошибка в Java коде). Убедитесь, что приходят правильные байты и если да, то составьте воспроизводимый пример на Java (здесь, либо в отдельном вопросе). Предполагаю, что каким-то образом записывается знаковый  бит, возможно, порядок байтов различается при приеме и передаче.

Comment: Немного ошибся и рано закрыл вопрос. Извиняюсь. С минусом оказывается считывает не getInt а обычный get. а getInt по прежнему ведёт себя не понятно. Сейчас опишу проблему поподробней.

Comment: вот последовательность которую я отправляю в 16-ричной системе `80 00 0f 00 19 00 00 00 af 00 00 00` Так как getInt берёт 4 байта. То я ему задал индекс 4. то есть он начнёт с 4 байта читать а там как раз число расписанное на 4 байта `19 00 00 00`. inData это base64. Вот как выглядит `gAAPABkAAACvAAAA` А вот что возвращает getInt(4) по тем условиям что я описал `419430400` Что я делаю не так? Или что я не понял?

Comment: При этом get(4) возвращает правильное значение, и без минуса. Как в случае с get(0).

Comment: Ничего не понятно, @Андрей . То одна последовательность, то другая, то с 0, то с 4, то -128, то 419430400. Сконцентрируйтесь на одной последовательности, локализуйте проблему, и создайте воспроизводимый пример наконец.

Comment: Последняя использумая мной выборка из 4 чисел это `128, 15, 25, 175` bcgjkmpe. getInt(4)  в моём случае должно вернуться число 25. Так как у меня числа хранятся так: 2 байта + 2 байта + 4 байта + 4байта. 419430400 это то что мне выдаёт getInt(4) хотя по логике должен вернуть 25. Вот как то так, надеюсь понятно.

Comment: @Андрей изложите все это в вопросе. И третий раз скажу про пример, может теперь сработает :)

Comment: Не на чем воспроизвести полноценный джавовский пример. Так как работаю с c#. Не подскажите может есть какой то онлайн компилятор для java наподобии таких как есть для c#?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67173/discussion-between-default-locale-and-).